# AutoMapper throwing type initializer exception...C#

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.5

I installed AutoMapper 3.1.0-ci1021 from NuGet via the Package manager console

```
 PM> Install-Package AutoMapper -Pre
```

I have 2 classes that are exactly the same:

```
public class FilterGroup1
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public object Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class FilterGroup2
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public object Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

I create (at least I try to create) a map for the objects:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<FilterGroup1, FilterGroup2>();
```

When I run my app, I get the following error:

> System.TypeInitilizationException
>   The type initializer for 'AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumMapper' threw an exception.
>   This type is not supported on this platform INullableConverterFactory

I'm using VS2012..NET 4.5. Does anyone have a clue as to what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure your project is referencing both the AutoMapper and AutoMapper.Net4 libraries. That error message usually shows up if AutoMapper.Net4 can't be found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447148/automapper-3-0-this-type-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-imapperregistry

If it is there are you using JetBrains resharper? There's some conversation concerning issue with it and AutoMapper here:https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/318

Comment: @Slump - thanks for your reply. The AutoMapper.Net4 dll is being referenced. I am using resharper. But when i run it on a standalone console app, it works fine even with resharper. On my MVC3 app, i'm getting the error. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @Slump - that maybe the problem. I am getting the error when I run my unit tests. My console app isnt being unit tested of course.

Comment: I'm only getting this error when i'm unit testing

Comment: Hmm, a user in that github thread mentions unchecking option here: Resharper->Options...->Tools->Unit Testing->MSTest->Use Legacy Runner fixed the issue for him. That said, my resharper doesn't seem to even have that option. Also, make sure you install the nuget package in you unit test projects, msbuild doesn't like to copy the AutoMapper libraries between projects like it should. You have to install it on each project using code that requires automapper.

Comment: @Slump - the problem was I needed to include AutoMapper and AutoMapper.Net4 references in the unit test project as well as the mvc project.

Comment: I had the same problem, i havent started writing my test cases yet. But looks like you just need to make sure to add the AutoMapper and AutoMapper.Net4 dlls to all projects using it. Doing this solved the problem